# Angular 10 matcher children not showing children

Tags: angular, children, angular-router, angular10

I'm trying to create a route pattern like this:

**/element** << -- show list of elements

**/element/1**  <<-- show detail of element 1

**/element/1/child** <<-- show list of children of element 1

I tried the path property ":id" and "child" but it's not working the children, neither the url, I changed it to use matchers, and first the url changed correctly to **/element/1/child** but the component shown is the parent even when the children matcher working with the url and also consuming well.

**Do I need to do something else? or is it a problem with mathcers?**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "/base", pathMatch: "full" },
      {
        path: "base",
        component: BaseComponent
      },
      {
        // path: ":id",
        matcher: (url) => {
          return url.length === 1
            ? {
                consumed: url.slice(0, 1),
                posParams: { id: new UrlSegment(url[0].path, {}) }
              }
            : { consumed: [] };
        },
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
          {
            // path: "child",
            matcher: (url) => {
              const result =
                url.length > 0
                  ? {
                      consumed: url,
                      posParams: { parentId: new UrlSegment(url[0].path, {}) }
                    }
                  : null;
              console.log("children entered", url); // it's entering
              console.log("consumed", result); // and consuming ok
              return result;
            },
            component: ChildrenComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Example Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-star-nr67j?file=/src/app/app.module.ts

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that's missing is an `router-outlet` in the **parent.component.html**:

```html
    <div>--- Parent ({{ id }}) ---</div>
    <div><a routerLink="/">Back</a></div>
    <a routerLink="/1/child">Child</a>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

There is a lot as to why this is needed, but a *rule of thumb* would be that a component from a route configuration which also has the children `property` must have at least one `router-outlet`. It is *at least* because you can have named outlets as well.

[CodeSandiox demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-kapitsa-ow3qo?file=/src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: Interesting, for mark as an accepted answer: the parent could be hidden if there's a children id in the route adding a simple *ngIf in html, but, Is there another way to do it from the router?

Comment: @Chrisdreams13 I’m not aware of any and I’m not sure it exists, since it’s not directly concerned. FWIW, I’d answer any question regarding angular router with pleasure, not need to add “conditions”.